# Filtering and prettyfying the response content of a django http request

Tags: python, django, httprequest, httpresponse

The following django middleware function is used to identify active links in a django response object. If a link is active, its marked with a css class and the href attribute gets replaced by `javascript:void(null);`. Using this function, the last two lines before the return statement are so slow that i cant use it, further, no css, js and images are rendered. However, if i put these two calls into the for loop, everything is fine and fast. But, i dont want these two calls executed for each active link on page, instead i want them executed only once, and that doesnt work, i really cant see why and what the for loop has to do with it. Its no BeautifulSoup issue, because its the same with `re.sub('\s+','',response.content)` or the replace function. As far as i have investigated this, i can tell you that the very last line before the return statement is the slow one, as long as its not executed inside the for loop. I'm really excited about a possible explanation.

```
import re  
from django_projects.projects.my_project.settings import SITE_NAME  
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup  

class PostRender():  
    def process_response(self, request, response):  
        link_pattern=re.compile('<a.*href="(http://%s)*%s".*>' % (SITE_NAME,request.path),re.IGNORECASE) 
        klass_pattern=re.compile('class="[^"]*"',re.IGNORECASE)  
        href_pattern=re.compile('href="(http://%s)*%s(\?.*)*"' % (SITE_NAME,request.path),re.IGNORECASE)  
        #find all active links
        search=re.finditer(link_pattern ,response.content)  
        for res in search:  
            result=res.group()  
            klassname='class="active"'  
            if 'class' in result:  
                klass=re.search(klass_pattern,result).group().split('=')[1]  
                if len(klass) != 0:  
                    klassname='class="%s %s"' % (klass[1:-1],'active')  
            link=re.sub(href_pattern,'href="javascript:void(null);"',re.sub(klass_pattern,klassname,result))  
            response.content=re.sub(result,link,response.content)  
        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content)  
        response.content=soup.prettify()  
        return response
```

Comment: why don't you use BeautifulSoup to find and replace the links? It is much more suited to this then regex?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i just read a tutorial explaining this soup thing, great!